# TSLint: how to disable all style/readability rules

Tags: webstorm, tslint

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to turn off all TSLint rules that have to do with code style/readability?  Barring that, is there a way to turn off all TSLint rules that don't pertain to whether my code will compile properly?

**Details:**
I'm using the WebStorm IDE for an Angular project, and it uses TSLint.  I like TSLint's real-time warnings/errors, as I am fairly new to JavaScript and the instant feedback streamlines my learning process.

However, I don't like how TSLint gives me warnings about style/formatting.  For example, if I don't put a space between two things or if I have a curly brace on a line by itself.  I want warnings to tell me about problems with my actual code, rather than someone's opinions about how my code should look.  I respect that they must be valuable to some people - I'm just not one of them.

On the official TSLint site's [rules page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/), it lists the rules I want to remove under a single category called "Style".  While I've found various posts about how to turn off individual rules like "[whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447602/tslint-remove-missing-whitespace-rule-on-import)", I haven't been able to dig up anything about how to disable this entire category of rules...and I'm hoping it exists, because there are a lot of rules.

Is there any way to do this without disabling every rule individually?

Answer (score 3):

According to the TSLint developers, TSLint has no rules active by default, so there should be no need to turn them off.  I mistakenly thought that TSLint had default rules, when in fact the actual problem was that someone else had put a tslint.json file in a directory I did not expect to find it in.  Relocating this file to a more appropriate place fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing does not exist. You can try filing an issue on https://github.com/palantir/tslint.

Have you tried manually disabling rules in your `tslint.json`?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting filing the issue, it lead me to the solution!  Saying so in a comment since I don't yet have upvote privileges.

Comment: Please, share the solution.