# How to enable "error prevention only" in TSLint? (Disable style checks, etc.)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tslint

I've just created and ran my first Vue.js + TypeScript project, but after I reformatted the typescript code to my favorite formatting, this is prompted in the `npm run serve` command prompt:

```
WARNING in .../src/app/app.ts
7:1 misplaced opening brace
     5 | })
     6 | export default class App extends Vue
  >  7 | {
       | ^
     8 |
     9 | }
    10 |
No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.5.3, tslint 5.18.0
Time: 1148ms
```

**Is there a way to enable only the error checks in TSLint without enabling any of the styling check rules?**

I tried to remove all the rules in `tslint.json` according to [TSLint: how to disable all style/readability rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025108/tslint-how-to-disable-all-style-readability-rules), but it still prompts the same warning.

My current `tslint.json` file:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "warning",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  }/*,
  "rules": {
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 4],
    "quotemark": [true, "single"]
  }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration option:

```
"extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ]
```

tells TSLint to use the built-in configuration preset `recommended`.

> **slint:recommended** is a stable, somewhat opinionated set of rules which we encourage for general TypeScript programming.

Removing the `extends` section will provide a clean slate. The default preset sources may be viewed [here](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/tree/master/src/configs).

You could also disable specific rules, such as:

```
"rules": { "curly": false }
```

Comment: Instead of disabling all the checks, if you take time to configure them to your preferred style, it will safe you time in the long run as it can automatically fix the problems.